# Background для UITableView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста как мне можно сделать кастомный Background для UITableView но что б тот смог уменьшаться и увиличиваться.

У меня есть небольшая полоска, высотой в 20.0f мне нужно что б она растянулась по высоте ячейки!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда создаете ячейку, загрузите ваше изображение в UIImageView, а потом этот imageView присвойте self.backgroundView, оно само растянет как надо.

Можно растянуть и не всю картинку а только часть, тогда используйте метод - (UIImage *)stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight.